# When web-crawling(scraping), "li: nth-child (n)" How do I increase the number n by +1?

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, web-crawler

I would like to use r to crawl my website. "li: nth-child (n)" I hope that n increases by 1 in this part.

```
 #cMain > div.section_bestseller > div.wrap_bestseller_rest > ul > li:nth-child(1) > dl > dt > a > strong
 #cMain > div.section_bestseller > div.wrap_bestseller_rest > ul > li:nth-child(2) > dl > dt > a > strong
 #li:nth-child(3),li:nth-child(4) ~ li:nth-child(10)
```

So I want to extract 1 to 10 in total. What should I do?

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

all.titles <- c()

for (page in 1:10){
  url='http://book.daum.net/bestseller/list.do?categoryID=SP1KOR00000&ymd=2017082&cpId=KY&pageNo='
  url_page <- paste0(url,page)
  reading_html <- read_html(url_page)

  text_nodes <- reading_html %>% html_node('div.section_bestseller') %>% html_nodes('div.wrap_bestseller_rest') %>% html_node('ul') %>% html_node('li:nth-child(1)') %>% html_node('dl')%>% html_node('dt')%>% html_node('a')   
  title <- html_text(text_nodes)
  all.titles<-c(all.titles, title)

  print(page)
}



result<-data.frame(all.titles)
```

Comment: @PoGibas I pressed f12 in chrome and made a copy selector for the area I wanted to extract.
That part is in #.

As I said in the title, li: nth-child (n) here I want to subtract n from 1 to 10. I go up and run only one number.

Comment: @and-bri 
I am still a beginner and I did not fully understand your comment. If you have 10 things like li: nth-child (1), li: nth-child (2) ~ li: nth-child (9), li: nth-child (10)

Comment: @and-bri  

Crawling is the process of getting what I want from a website.

(scraping = crawling)
The address I crawl is listed in the "url" section of the code above.

Comment: what is crawling?? you want to download the content of this site?

Comment: @and-bri  
http://book.daum.net/bestseller/list.do?categoryID=SP1KOR00000&ymd=2017082&cpId=KY&pageNo=

On this page,
#cMain> div.section_bestseller> div.wrap_bestseller_rest> ul> li: nth-child (1)> dl> dt> a> strong
I want to download the part here. Through R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an XML parser to get the information from the site ([scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)):

```
out <- NULL
for(z in 1:10){
  url='http://book.daum.net/bestseller/list.do?categoryID=SP1KOR00000&ymd=2017082&cpId=KY&pageNo='
  hh <- htmlParse(paste0(url,z))
  a <- xpathSApply(hh, "//div[@class='wrap_bestseller_rest']/*/*/*/dt/a/strong", xmlValue)
  out <- cbind(out, a)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But in this case, I can fetch only one page of information T_T (at the end of the URL there is a page number, which I also need to bring up to 10 pages)